# Gremlin: Get list of vertices that do not have certain property fields

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

I want to find a list of people that are missing at least one of these properties: Title, DisplayName, FirstName,LastName, Id, Email.

I have tried the below but get an error 
"java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

If I only run the first three lines, I am getting results for people that do not have a DisplayName with empty values for that property, however there is no property column for Title.

```
g.V().hasLabel('people').hasNot('Title')
.or().hasLabel('people').hasNot('DisplayName')
.or().hasLabel('people').hasNot('FirstName')
.or().hasLabel('people').hasNot('LastName')
.or().hasLabel('people').hasNot('Id')
.or().hasLabel('people').hasNot('Email')
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you overcomplicate the query? Who not just this:

```
g.V().hasLabel('people').not(
    has('Title').has('DisplayName').
    has('FirstName').has('LastName').
    has('Id').has('Email'))
```

However, it's not really clear to me what your expectation is (the statement "however there is no property column for Title" is kinda confusing), but maybe the rewritten query will already help you (if not, then please provide some sample data and the expected result, that always makes it much easier to answer traversal-related questions).